# $3\sum_{sym}x^2y^2z+\sum_{sym}x^4y\ge 4\sum_{sym}x^3yz$

Tags: inequality, summation, symmetric-polynomials, sum-of-squares-method

Prove that
$$3\sum_{sym}x^2y^2z+\sum_{sym}x^4y\ge 4\sum_{sym}x^3yz,\quad\forall x,y,z>0,$$
where $\sum_{sym}$ is the [symmetric sum notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality#Symmetric_sum_notation).

Context: I was reading about the Muirhead inequality and I was wondering if I take a convex combination between 2 symmetric sums $S_0$ and $S_1$: $S_{\alpha}=\alpha S_1+(1-\alpha)S_0$, where $S1\ge S\ge S_0$ and $S$ is also a symmetric sum, then is there a tactic to prove that $S_{\alpha}\le S$ or $S_{\alpha}\ge S$? I took the particular case in the problem and I tested it in a program, by generating many random triples, and I didn't find a counterexample. I tried to use AM-GM or to rewrite the inequality to use the Schur inequality, but without an improvement. I believe this type of inequalities are of interest for those who participate in math contests.

Comment: How is $S$ related to $\alpha$? If there is no relation, you seem to be asking how to compare a random symmetric sum wrt another random symmetric sum?

Comment: @CalvinLin You are right, the question is too vague. I hoped that the convex combination will force one of the inequalities: $S_{\alpha}\le S$ or $S_{\alpha}\ge S$ to hold for any triple, but, unfortunately, there are convex combinations for which this is not true. However, the above particular inequality I believe is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $$\sum_{sym}(3x^2y^2z+x^4y-4x^3yz)=\sum_{cyc}(x^4z+y^4z-x^3yz-y^3xz-6x^3yz+6x^2y^2z)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2(z(x^2+xy+y^2)-3xyz)=\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^4z\geq0.$$

Comment: Meanwhile, I tried the BW and it seems to work also (I will put the answer below).

Answer (score 0):

By the Buffalo Way, we take wlog $y=x+u$, $z=x+v$, $u,v\ge0$, and after some computations the inequality is equivalent with
\begin{align*}
2u^4x+2v^4x-4u^3vx-4v^3ux+6u^2v^2x+u^4v+v^4u\ge0\\
\Leftrightarrow 2x(u^2-uv)^2+2x(v^2-uv)^2+2u^2v^2x+u^4v+v^4u\ge0.
\end{align*}